# Which tool can be used to extract and group rows and do the summation?

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

[image]

I would like to extract and group the table using the columns 'ELEMENTID', 'FID_waterdemand2044' and 'Demand' as shown in the figure below. Also i need to sum the Demand values. What tool can be used for this purpose in excel?

[image]

Comment: Well, for the sum you can use SUMIFS()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Pivot table (Insert/Pivot table) and select the fields as in the picture, and then add a sum for the rightest column (Sum of Demand) manually

[image: pivot table]

This setting will cause this: (I only filled two rows from your data)
[image: pivot tbale2]

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on assuming your data starts in cell A1, then the following will work to sum data per Element_ID:

```
=SUMIFS(F2:F13,D2:D13,31)
```

[image]